# Can we zoom the image to full size of device as media player in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview, media-player

We can zoom media player to full size in iOS by pitch action.How to implement this type of zooming in the case of ImageView in iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Steps :**

**1)** You need to add the `UIImageView` as a subview of a `UIScrollView`.

**2)** Install a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the scroll view and set the `numberOfTapsRequired` property to **1**.

**3)** In the callback method of the gesture recognizer, just set the `zoomScale` property of the scroll view to your desired zoom amount.

**4)** Don't forget to set `maximumZoomScale` and `minimumZoomScale` on the `UIScrollView` as well.

Answer (score 0):

- Add Pinch Recognizer to imageView
- Inside the recognizer method - set image view frame to full view size with animation
- Also hide status bar using `[setStatusBarHidden:YES]` on UIApplication